# Webkit not playing nice with youtube iframe embed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webkit

So, I have a fresh new rails app [here](https://github.com/KeysetTS/Bad-Youtube) and I want to allow users to embed youtube videos in posts they make. The following takes place

User visits /posts/new
User puts `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bzvH8k6NUs4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` into body textarea.
User clicks 'create post'

The user is then presented with the post created but nothing is show in the iframe where the youtube video should be.
[image]
HTML
[image]

The User has to refresh the page in order to see the video. This is specific only to webkit browsers. So, could someone explain to me what is going on here? Is there some error in my redirect process or the way I am rendering the show view?